# Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: rviz

[image: Rosanswers logo]

HI ALL , as i run command

rosrun rviz rviz

rviz screen opens and closes immediately and i get following code

Config file '/home/sanket/.rviz/config' could not be opened for reading.

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38228/segmentation-fault-(core-dumped)/) by [Sanket_Kumar](https://answers.ros.org/users/2789/sanket_kumar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 234 on 2012-07-08

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Couple of things to try / check:

1. Does the file `/home/sanket/.rviz/config` exist?
2. What are its permissions?
3. Is it corrupted / damaged in any way?
4. If it exists, remove it, try again.
5. Check out one of the many other threads with 'rviz' and 'segfault' in their title: [1](http://answers.ros.org/question/11376/rviz-segmentation-fault-at-launch/), [2](http://answers.ros.org/question/12043/rosrun-rviz-rviz-segmentation-fault/), [3](http://answers.ros.org/question/11809/rviz-crashing-at-startup-with-baddrawable/), etc.
6. Check the [rviz troubleshooting](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rviz/Troubleshooting#Segfault_during_startup) section on its wiki.

---

Another option (perhaps the first) is to run rviz in GDB. Then get a backtrace. It seems you have coredumps enabled, so you could do a post-mortem debugging session (see [here](http://cgi.cse.unsw.edu.au/%7Ecs3231/doc/debug.php) for some info (just a random link, just use a search engine for more)).

---

Originally posted by [ipso](https://answers.ros.org/users/2486/ipso/) with karma: 1416 on 2012-07-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1